# C# to MS Access.mdb 2007 ODBC connection "Thread Failed To Start" Error

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

We are using a c# application (Ranorex) to connect to a Microsoft Access (.mdb) database using an ODBC Connection.  During a single run of the code we receive no errors and the connection is made successfully.
Basically the code opens a connection to the DB, retrieves data from the database and then we use the .close method on the database connection when we're done.
However when the code is run continually in a loop after a couple of days the following error is displayed:
"Thread Failed To Start".
This happens at the point the ODBC connection is (attempted) to open.
Does anybody have any suggestions as how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Very difficult to say, but remember, a connection should not only be closed, but you should also dispose it. Try to encapsulate your connection with the using statement (if possible)

Comment: Thanks Steve, Should we use close and dispose or just dispose?

Comment: I will add an answer as an example to better explain the code

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example. I cannot answer your question with a direct reference to your code, because, well there is no code to look at. However, the pattern to follow when working with expensive resources like database connections is always the same: `Create, Open, Use, Close, Destroy`

```
using(OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString))
using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(commantText, con))
{
   OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
   con.Open();
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds, "Table");
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) play a fundamental role here. When the code exits from the using block, the command is disposed, the connection is closed and then disposed. **Also if you get an Exception in the middle of the using block**. It is a very handy replacemente for writing `try{....}finally{close/dispose}`. Of course I cannot claim that this will resolve your problems, but nevertheless this is the correct `first aid` to apply to your code.

Comment: Hey Steve, I've only recently started using `using` (so to speak) and I was under the impression that for multiple type declarations the syntax is `using(type1, type2) {`. This is the first time I've seen `using(type1) using(type2) {`. Is that a legal alternate syntax?

Comment: Yes it is an impression because that syntax is not allowed. You receive.... `Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or declaration statement`

Comment: Aha, okay thanks! I looked at the docs again and multiple *instances* of the *same type* are allowed, not multiple *types*. I'm learning....